# Content aligns left when overflowing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get these bullet lists to both start from the centre. I have noticed that when the length of the text exceeds the width of the browser window, the bullet points align to the left of the page. Why is this and how can I get it to align centrally? Is this an overflow issue? I cannot work out how to solve this problem.

Appreciate the help, thank you.

```css
.standard-list-wrap{
    padding-top: 25px;
    display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

ul.standard-list{
 padding:0px 0 50px 00000;
 margin:0;
 text-align:left;
 color:#000;
 font-weight:100;
 font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:20px;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* subtley makes fonts smoother */
 line-height:28px;
}

ul.standard-list li{
 list-style-type: none;
 line-height:28px;
}
ul.standard-list li:before{
    /* Unicode bullet symbol */
    content: '\2022';
    /* Bullet color */
    color: #f0f;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="standard-list-wrap">
        
<ul class="standard-list">
          <li>shorter text is no problem</li>
          <li>shorter text is no problem</li>
    </ul>
        
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="standard-list-wrap">
        
<ul class="standard-list">
          <li>but when the text gets too long the problem occurs because the div is no longer centralised and list floats to the left of the page - i want the bullet points to be centralised like the above</li>
    </ul>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: As DIV takes 100% width, when content is large full width is utilised. To fix this issue you can set width of ul tag to some size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

element will take 100% width when text content gets too long

maybe you could set a max-width for your list item

```css
.standard-list-wrap {
    padding-top: 25px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

ul.standard-list {
    padding: 0px 0 50px 00000;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    /* subtley makes fonts smoother */
    line-height: 28px;
}

ul.standard-list li {
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 28px;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}

ul.standard-list li:before {
    /* Unicode bullet symbol */
    content: '\2022';
    /* Bullet color */
    color: #f0f;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="standard-list-wrap">

    <ul class="standard-list">
        <li>shorter text is no problem</li>
        <li>shorter text is no problem</li>
    </ul>

</div>



<div class="standard-list-wrap">

    <ul class="standard-list">
        <li>but when the text gets too long the problem occurs because the div is no longer centralised and list floats to the left of the page - i want the bullet points to be centralised like the above</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

:

```
ul.standard-list li{
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height:28px;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**You must assign width for `li` :**

```
ul.standard-list li{
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height:28px;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 250px;
}
```

**Full Code :**

```css
   .standard-list-wrap{
    padding-top: 25px;
    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul.standard-list{
  padding:0px 0 50px 00000;
  margin:0;
  text-align:left;
  color:#000;
  font-weight:100;
  font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:20px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* subtley makes fonts smoother */
  line-height:28px;
}

ul.standard-list li{
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height:28px;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 250px;

}
ul.standard-list li:before{
    /* Unicode bullet symbol */
    content: '\2022';
    /* Bullet color */
    color: #f0f;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="standard-list-wrap">   
      <ul class="standard-list">
                <li>shorter text is no problem</li>
                <li>shorter text is no problem</li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
    
    <div class="standard-list-wrap">  
    <ul class="standard-list">
          <li>but when the text gets too long the problem occurs because the div is no longer centralised and list floats to the left of the page - i want the bullet points to be centralised like the above</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```